# Question about the convergence of an infinite series in all of $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta

Does the following infinite series:

$$G(s):=\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s + \frac{1}{n^s}}$$

converge for all $s \in \mathbb{C}$ (especially in the critical strip; since when $\Re(s) \rightarrow \infty$, then $G(s) \rightarrow \frac12$ ) ?

Note that $G(s)=G(-s)$. **EDIT** Based on good feedback in the comments: the series clearly diverges for $s=0$. A possible analytic continuation of $G(s)$ at that point, could be to use Grandi's series, that has a Cesàro sum of $\frac12$, hence $G(0)$ might be 'assigned' a value of $\frac14$.

Comment: Doesn't $G(0)$ diverge?

Comment: At $s=0$ the series becomes $\frac12$ * Grandi's series that has a Cesàro sum of $\frac12$, hence $G(0)$ could be assigned a value of $\frac14$.

Comment: I see.. that's how we role :), that result still unnerves me

Comment: @ellya. Same here, but started to get used to it somewhat :) You are right though, that I should articulate this much sharper in my question. The series do diverge for $G(0)$ in the usual sense and I was already applying/presuming some analytic continuation. Will correct it.

Comment: @Agno The series doesn't converge, and at $0$ it does in fact diverge. You could say that $G(s)=\Sigma(s)$ for some range of values $s$ and then you could say $G(0)=\frac{1}{4}$, but it would not be correct to say $\Sigma(0)=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Ethan. Got it and corrected it in the question.

Comment: It's worth investigating specifically the convergence at $s=i$, say, where $G(i) = \sum_n (-1)^{n+1}/2\cos(\log n)$.

Comment: Greg, $G(i)$ (and all $\Re(s)=0$) indeed also diverges when evaluating the series, however Maple does assign the value $-13.23372427475...$ (guess some form of analytic continuation is applied). Not sure how to calculate this number, but is seems to be the average value of an infinite amount of finite odd and finite even series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about on the imaginary axis, but $G(s)$ converges for all $s$ with nonzero real part. Since $G(-s)=G(s)$, it suffices to consider $\Re s>0$. Choose an integer $k\ge(2\Re s)^{-1}$. Then
\begin{align*}
G(s) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}(1+n^{-2s})^{-1}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \bigg( \sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^{j-1} n^{-(2j-1)s} + \bigg( n^{-s}(1+n^{-2s})^{-1} - \sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^{j-1} n^{-(2j-1)s} \bigg) \bigg) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^j \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n n^{-(2j-1)s} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \bigg( n^{-s}(1+n^{-2s})^{-1} - \sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^{j-1} n^{-(2j-1)s} \bigg),
\end{align*}
assuming that these $k+1$ infinite series all converge. But
in the first sum, each of the $k$ inner sums converges for real $s>0$ by the alternating series test, and hence converges for all $s$ with $\Re s>0$ by the general theory of Dirichlet series. As for the second sum, the $n$th term is $O(n^{-(2k+1)s})$, and so that series converges absolutely at $s$ by our choice of $k$.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I tested convergence with increasingly higher finite series and it also seems to work for the imaginary axis for $\Re(s) \ne 0$, however indeed difficult to prove.